# I can not import this file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I can not import/ link my RMarkDown to my dataset

Show in New Window

```
Error in read.spss("X03_France3_Data", to.data.frame = TRUE) : 
  unable to open file: 'No such file or directory'
```

i am trying to import my data set or link it i am a beginner and this brings me a lot of trouble

Comment: Are the rmd and the sav files in the same directory? Are one of them in a subdirectory?

Comment: There are in the normal dictionary

Comment: What happens if you run `read.spss("X03_France3_Data.sav")`